# Why is my X11 app's save dialogue suddenly defaulting to "Recently Saved" in Places sidebar?

Tags: fedora, x11

I make a lot of text files using a basic text editor (in the F15 with Xfce DE I use Leaf). Recently the save dialogue is defaulting the "Places" sidebar to "Recently Used" where before it was always my home directory. This adds an extra step to my routines, because you can't save to "Places". And for the same reason the change is obvious, real, and aggravating.

Answer (score 1):

http://tstarling.com/blog/2011/11/file_chooser_recent/

Apparently, this is a change made to GTK recently. I have the same on my laptop and I can confirm that it's annoying. There doesn't seem to be a fix (except reverting the update in question or recompiling it all yourself) but let's hope that the developers take notice.

Sorry I can't be of more use.

Answer (score 0):

you may be interested in using Scribes an another text editor which has the option. [scribes](http://scribes.sourceforge.net) see  for more information
[this](https://superuser.com/questions/74883/changing-gedits-default-file-open-save-path)

Comment: _"There is no way of changing the default to always be a specific location unless you edit the source."_ This is humorous, because it changed all by itself. Its not intermittent, but evidently permanent. haha Be that as it may, your answer is not really an _answer_, though I appreciate the sentiment.